# Can be ∑P/k! be broken down in a expression without the sum?

Tags: probability, summation, factorial

I am doing probability counting. After some time spent on counting i have this formula.

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{P}{k!}$$

Can it be resolved to formula without the sum? This factorial is really annoying.

Comment: That's a partial sum of the series for the exponential. For large $n$ it will be very close to $eP$. But if you want an exact formula. that's about the best you'll get.

Comment: On second tought, there could be $$P\frac{\left\lfloor n!e\right\rfloor}{n!}=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{P}{k!}.$$